# Angular 6: display login form along with controls to the center of the screen

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular6

I'm creating a Reactive form in Angular 6. 
In typescript file I'm getting the form instance and form controls.
after that iterating through the form controls and printing the user given values.
When do **ng serve** in the console of the browser I'm getting the error.

Here is the code.
**html**

```
<div >
<h2>Login</h2>
<form class='form' [formGroup]='loginForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" 
    placeholder="Username" 
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }"/>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
  placeholder="Password"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }"/>
     <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button [disabled]="loading" type="submit" class="btn btn- 
 primary">Login</button>
</div>
```

My form fields are displaying whole screen. Please see the attached image.
[image]
But I want to display all the controls to the center of the screen.
i.e. I need place left,right,top and bottom equal space.
Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: LoginComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:

       
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

Answer (score 0):

The error throws because of the wrong formGroup name. In the ts file you have created the formGroup name as `loginFormGroup` and in the html the formGroup name is 'loginForm'. change it like this

```
<form class='form' [formGroup]='loginFormGroup' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
```

Comment: yes, cleared the error. My form is displaying whole screen. How can I restrict and align to center.

Answer (score 0):

give your top most div class suppose **makeItCenter** and add following css

```css
.makeItCenter {
  width: 50rem;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

place the whole form tag in

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-offset-3">
set your form here
</div>
</div>
```

this is simple bootstrap